# Is there any way you can compute a scattering amplitude using quantum information?

Tags: quantum-information, ads-cft

Are there any applications of quantum information theory in particle physics? I hear a it a lot in talks (e.g Erik Verlinde). For example is there any way you can compute a scattering amplitude using quantum information?(also there is a connection through AdS/CFT?) Or is there any calculation we can do through quantum information that applies to supergravity?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Information Field Theory. Not sure if it's exactly what you have in mind, but Torsten Enßlin has statistical techniques that end up being computed using Feynman diagrams... I only sat in his class for a bit, but I found it extremely interesting and mind-boggling that this even exists. The techniques are also not just an abstraction, they were used in imaging the cosmic microwave background for example.

Lecture notes: https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/~ensslin/lectures/Files/ScriptIT&IFT.pdf

Home page: https://www.mpa-garching.mpg.de/109183/Information-Field-Theory

Comment: Wow that's interesting! Information theory is litterally everywhere.

Comment: very unexpected connection, to say the least